# Can i add array to single field in MS-Access Database?

Tags: ms-access

I've an access database. i want to create a column in my table in which fields can store array or collection of strings or numbers etc.. 
For example i created a table Cars : Model (String) , Colors_Available(array of strings).
Is that possible in Microsoft Access ? please help .

Comment: This is not a good idea. Use separate tables before it turns around and bites. Such a set-up makes sensible data retrieval very difficult.

Comment: In A2007 and A2010, you have multi-value fields available, so you can do this. It's not recommended, but it *is* possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is; the alternative is to store it as text separated by comma, and in your code, split it before you access it.

HTH.

Comment: This is correct +1, a delimited string would be fine. Consider using a separate table. You can embed objects, but that would be overkill.